# Счетчик просмотров товаров php

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

Как сделать счетчик просмотра товаров, архитектура mvc , нужна логика счетчика для детальной страницы товара

Comment: Ну, сделать контроллер, анализирующий данные пользователя и генерирующий картинку со счётчиком. Учёт уникальных пользователей можно реализовать, используя куки, например. Вместо или вместе с куками можно использовать другие параметры для точного определения. Можно покопать по направлению неудаляемых кук (evercookie). Данных подход применяется не только для MVC.

Comment: А методом обойтись никак?Есть таблица product в ней столбец views

Comment: Смотря как вы собираетесь реализовать счётчик. Если подразумевается использование на разных страницах, то проще вынести всю логику в отдельных контроллер, который на выходе будет генерировать картинку. А на нужных страницах добавить обычную картинку с URL контроллера-счётчика: `<img src="http://site.ru/counter">`. Контент для вывода формирует view, вычисления - в моделе, а контроллер, грубо говоря, запрашивает данные, у моделей и отдаёт view'шкам (ну, это очень упрощённо), а потом всё это отправляет клиенту.

Comment: Под методом вы подразумеваете функцию-член класса контроллера?

Answer (score 0):

как вариант: создать табличку в бд (id, product, ip-user), при просмотре товара в бд будет попадать запись - пользователь с таким то ip, посмотрел такой то товар. потом в коде вытаскиваете количество просмотров нужного товара